# Administering Team Foundation Server 2010 from Local PC

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have TFS Server 2010 installed on a remote server.

I have some Windows users on this server for different members of our team.

I connected to the TFS Server using Visual Studio 2010 (installed on my local PC) and am trying to set up security permissions for some of the TFS users.

However, I am unable to do that, as from Team Explorer plugin in Visual Studio, I can see only the local users on my PC.

It seems that I need to install Visual Studio 2010 (or Team Explorer 2010) on TFS server! This seems a bit inconvenient. Are there other ways to solve this problem? Can I do without installing Team Explorer on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added yourself to the Project Collection Administrators group?

Go to the Team Foundation Server Console on the server, 'Server Name' > Application Tier > Team Project Collections > select the Team Project Collection > select Group Membership on the right
Double click the Project Collection Administrators entry and add your user account.

Comment: How can I add my user account on the SERVER if this is my LOCAL PC account? The server and local PC are not on the same network. I am connecting to TFS via Internet.